# Question about using API to retrieve cell data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I’m wondering if someone could help me figure out a little issue I’m having. I’m trying to create an iOS shortcut to retrieve specific cell data from a Google Sheets document, and I’m really close, however, I’m hitting this snafu.

For my example, the data entered into the specific cell is: “0+ 5” (without the quotes).

I’m using the following URL to grab the data (with my string ID and API keys X’d out):

> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/XXXXXXXXXX/values/Sheet1!D#?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

(Also, the **#** character after “Sheet1!D” is purposeful….I have shortcuts configured to replace that character with a number I input when running the shortcut)

Anyway, the result I’m getting is:

> {"range":"Sheet1!D99","majorDimension":"ROWS","values":[["0+  5"]]}

*Notice the “0+ 5” near the end, which is the data entered in the specific cell.*

I know I can mess around with Regex to to have the shortcut specifically match that part of the text, but I’m assuming there’s a way to format the API URL so that it *only* gives me the data entered — in this case, **only**

> 0+ 5

and not all of the other info….am I correct in that assumption? If so, I’d rather go that route and have the shortcut be a bit less convoluted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Server's response is in JSON format, meaning, you can use action **Get Dictionary From Input** and next use action **Get Dictionary Value**. Type in **values** for the key.

Check this image:

[image: enter image description]

Hope this helps.